# Spring-Boot | loading different messages.properties files for different clients/users dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, thymeleaf

I searched a lot but I can't find any useful information on my topic. Let me explain.

I created a spring application that can change its layout based on the user that is logged in. This layout can be uploaded by an admin. Now I want to add a function that the admin can upload a specific `messages.properties` for this user, so the texts change based on the logged in user as well. The templates that I created with thymeleaf are always the same. So the message keys are the same, just the values are changing.

I tried to create a dynamic `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` but that is not working because at the configuration time you don't know what the name of the `messages.propertie` will be.

Do I just don't get it? I don't know. Is there any way to create a dynamic `messages.properties`-loader that can identify the file with a name like:
messages_foo_de_DE.properties

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Please update your question with test code( Spring boot + thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep locale or language preference associated with user. Once the user logged in you know the current user locale or language. Now you can set the locale using [LocaleResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html)

```
LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
Locale userLocale = new Locale('de')// Locale loaded dynamically from DB or url parameter.

localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, userLocale );
```

Comment: this is not about locale resolving. it depends on a user or client

Comment: I understood it depends on user/client, but your locale with do the tricks when user login. Default locale will be changed based on current user locale.

Comment: I currently working to archive this, and the local is set to my custom locale but still spring only looks for `messages_de_DE.properties` and not for `messages_foo_bar.properties`. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. `propsFileName`, `property`, and `value` can be supplied as arguments

```
    @Autowired
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSrc;

    void updateProperty(String property, String value, String propsFileName) {
     boolean success = false;
     Properties props = new Properties();
     FileOutputStream output = null;
     FileInputStream configStream = null;
     try {
        configStream = new FileInputStream(propsFileName);
        props.load(configStream);
        props.setProperty(property, value);
        // save modified property file
        output = new FileOutputStream(propsFileName);
        props.store(output, "This description goes to the header of a file");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
    } finally {
        if (configStream != null) {
            try {
                configStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    }


     messageSrc.clearCache();
}
```

Comment: I think I don't want to update my property values. Also, the problem is that when a user logs in I have to load the right `messages.properties` but how do I do that?